# Plane ticket for infant

Tags: tickets, airports, airlines, children

I am trying to book a flight for my wife and 2 kids from my home country to the country where I currently reside.
My oldest kid is 19 months and the other one is 8 months.
I tried booking to our preferred airline and since the airline only allows 1 infant per 1 adult, I booked 1 adult, 1 infant and 1 child.

The airline specifically says in their website that:

"Two infants with one adult:
If second infant is over 12 months and able to sit on a seat with a seat belt; Second infant shall travel having paid Child fare".

However, when I try to book online, I couldn't continue with the booking since an error says that my child must be at least 2 yrs old to be book with a child ticket. I tried booking thru customer service but they keep insisting that it would be difficult to travel with 2 infants, even if I told them that my eldest child can already sit and walk. And also, my wife will be flying on the same flight with her friend whom we have asked to sit beside my family and help my wife with the kids while in the airport and on the plane. However, her friend already has a ticket.

My question is, would it be too risky to put in wrong birthday for my oldest child (make the website think she's 2 yrs old+) and continue with the booking?

How often do airlines check the passenger's birthday if it matches the one in his/her passport? Would a wrong birthday be enough reason for offloading?

Answer (score 4):

Few options for you in situation :

1/ Call the airline directly. They might be able to make a phone booking that will allow bypassing this online booking issue.

2/ Use a 3rd party website to perform the booking that also won't have this kind of problem.

I would really discourage you to input wrong details for the sole purpose of going through the booking process. You have a good probability to be caught and this might lead into problems. They will eventually deny boarding and even worse not refund your tickets. So to be on the safe side, call them or use an alternate website.

Comment: +1 for calling the airline.  Basically, you're flying with an infant but need a child fare so they get their own seat, and this is sufficiently rare that most online booking tools can't handle it.

Comment: Sounds like they've already tried contacting the airline - "I tried booking thru customer service but they keep insisting that it would be difficult to travel with 2 infants" - though if they tried again they might get somebody who is less concerned about how difficult it *might be* for them to travel.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist "keep insisting" may indicate that several attempts have already been made.

Comment: Yes I did tried calling the airlines 3x to clarify this and if they can do something about it but no luck. But I did went to their ticketing office and luckily I was assigned to a supervisor/manager. The airlines would not allow 2 infants on 1 adult. The infant cannot have a child ticket if he/she is under 2 yrs old. So I told them about my wife's friend that is booked on the same flight and the manager said that I should attach my wife's friend's flight details and then they issued 1 infant each for my wife and her friend for the flight.

Comment: And yes, putting wrong information on flight tickets is absolutely a no no. I was just getting desperate so my apologies :-)